# Do the variable names given as 'VarLabels' in biplot (MATLAB) follow the same order as the original matrix given for PCA?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, naming-conventions, pca

I have a MATLAB matrix with over 6000 observations and 10 variables for each observation. I did PCA on this matrix and want to plot the scores using `biplot`. In order to see the effect of each variable, I want to specify labels with `'VarLabels'`. I gave the variable names in the same order as the columns in the original matrix, but I'm not sure if in the resulting biplot, my variables are labelled correctly or not.

Could any one shed some light on this please?

Comment: I believe they are, or at least they seem to be, having a look at the demos

Comment: Thank you so much !